# Cisco Anyconnect 4.4 .pcf location on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

None of the locations from prior versions of Anyconnect or macOS seem to be valid anymore. I have the profiles (still located at `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile`) but I'm looking for the `.pcf` file so I can extract the shared secret.

Help?